# how to clone div value to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I need to copy a value from a "Div" to an "input" by clicking the button.

the function is copying the whole div html value, contrary to what i need, i want to copy only the text.

view example: https://jsfiddle.net/fg79vypb/

```js
$('#copy').on('click', function() {
      $('#message').val($('<div/>').append($('#whatsapp').clone()).html());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button id="copy">Get order on WhatsApp</button>
    <div id="whatsapp" style="    position: fixed;     width: 200px;     height: auto;     bottom: 40px;     right: 40px;     background-color: #e0ffe7;     border-radius: 10px; padding-left: 10px;     border-top-width: 10px;     padding-top: 10px;     padding-bottom: 10px;"><span class="simpleCart_total">R$ 18.00</span> (<span class="simpleCart_quantity" id="simpleCart_quantity">1</span> items)
     <br><br>
    <div class="simpleCart_items"><div class="cartHeaders"><div class="itemName">Name</div><div class="itemPrice">Price</div><div class="itemQuantity">Quantity</div><div class="item"></div></div><div class="itemContainer"><div class="itemName">Product name 1</div><div class="itemPrice">R$ 18.00</div><div class="itemQuantity">1</div><div class="item"> </div></div></div>
    <a class="simpleCart_empty" href="javascript:;">clean cart</a>
    <br><br>
    <a class="simpleCart_checkout" href="javascript:;">go to checkout</a></div>
    <input id="message" type="text" >
```

I would like to get only the text value, and is displaying all html code.

Comment: thanks for the reply i would like to capture the session:"Product name 1" and "R$ 18.00"

all are returning copying all source code

Comment: So you want to be able to capture multiple(s) then as well? In case the user has more than just one item in the cart or selection? Or is this always going to be a singular ?? I am unable to help you until you add more information

Comment: My project is based on simplecartjs.org that you create products, and the idea is basically to capture all items and values and send them as a new order via whattsapp as at the following link: https://subversivo58.github.io/lab/whatsapp-send.html

The captured values go to the input and will be sent to the user.

sorry about my English

Comment: So, you are telling me that you want to grab all the product names and prices that the user has selected and pass those to the server via the textbox? And I take it this needs to capture multiple products for a correct solution? Also, what format does the whattsapp expect to receive? JSON, plain text, html?

Comment: yes that would be fantastic if it were possible, so a user would place an order and you would get it straight to your smartphone

Comment: jquery and pure javascript: 
an example:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=847358979876&text=this%20is%20the%20value%20obtained%20ifrom%20checkout

Comment: Please see updated answer.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson the first example you sent was great

Answer (score 1):

This code will do what you want. Just copy text not html code

```
$('#copy').on('click', function() { 
  $('#message').val($('#whatsapp').text());
});
```

Comment: thank you so much dude, you are top!
helped me a lot! it was exactly what I needed. ^^

Comment: you're welcome. if it solve your problem then you can accept the solution for your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to capture all item names and their prices and place them into an array using `JQuery`. You can then decide what you want to do with them from there:

```
let items = []; //Declare an array which will hold all items selected by user
let valueForTextbox = "";
//Iterate each name and grab it's corresponding price:
$('.itemName').each(function(){
   //Check for the header row, so we don't place titles into the array
   if($(this).text() !== 'Name'){
       items.push({ ItemName: $(this).text(), ItemPrice: $(this).next('.itemPrice').text() });
   }
});

 //Display each item's name and price
 items.forEach(function(item){
   //Concat the item names and item prices
   valueForTextbox += item.ItemName + " " + item.ItemPrice + " ");
});

 //Set the textbox value
 $('#message').val(valueForTextbox);
 //You can then format each item to whatever you need from here
```

Comment: exactly, instead of alert, I would like to insert the value into the input: <input id="message" type="text" >

Comment: @ThiagoVinic Then I think you should be able to do so using my code example. I changed it to concatenate the item name with their prices into one string and set the textbox value.